# How to change my tables to views in liquibase xml?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, view, liquibase

I am new to postgres sql and liquibase. In my xml database we are just using tables. I am attempting to incorporate it to views. From my understanding, we can replace tables with having views, or use the view to call the table data?

So if I had a table that looked like this in the xml database:

```
 <changeSet author="example" id="insert-table">
            <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
            <sql dbms="postgresql">SET SEARCH_PATH TO ${database.defaultSchemaName}</sql> <!-- workaround for https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2234 -->
            <insert tableName="table">
                <column name="table_id" value="0"/>
           </insert>
```

And we using querys to get the to table's data in Spring Boot java doing:

```
@Repository
public interface Repo extends JpaRepository<Table, String> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Mission> findTableByTableId(String tableId);
}
```

Is it a simple change to just have it selecting from the view instead of the table? I am struggleing to find documentation or examples of this. I see https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-view.html that shows how to create the table in XML, but how can I replace these tables with views?

Comment: A table and a view are two separate things and tend to be used for different purposes. A view tends to be used where you have a specific data set you want to query as if it were a table. Why do you want to "replace" your table with a view?

Comment: We want to see if using a materialized view could potentially be better than using tables. So instead of having all these different tables we use views instead, just to see if it is a better approach.

Comment: If I understand correctly, once you've created your view you want to query that rather than the table? In which case you just amend your SQL query in code to call that view, much in the same way you would a table.